# Apple Pay in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, applepay

Help me please. How to integrate Apple Pay in Xamarin.Forms? The instruction that is on the Microsoft website does not provide a step-by-step algorithm for implementing this functionality.
Maybe there is a plugin that helps solve this problem? I tried to register at www.judopay.com, as indicated in the Microsoft manual, but no one answered my application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct detail tutorial in Xamrarn , however Xamrin provide [a Emporium sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/ios9-emporium/) and [original document from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/apple-pay) to explain that .

The sample app is comprised of several parts:

- `CatalogCollectionViewController` - a collection view that displays a list of products (parsed from `ProductsList.plist`)
- `ProductTableViewController` - a detail table view that summarizes a product, and allows the user to buy it using Apple Pay
- `ConfirmationViewController` - a simple confirmation screen to be shown after a successful payment

Hope this sample will be helpful to create your first apple pay application .

In addition , the most important logic is **Processing the Payment Token**:

> Once the user has authenticated to confirm purchase intent, you don’t need to handle their actual credit or debit card numbers. Instead, your app or website receives a payment object containing an encrypted payment token. This token encapsulates the information needed to complete a payment transaction, including the device-specific account number, the amount, and a unique, one-time-use cryptogram. The token can be decrypted by the merchant with the certificate private key or by the Payment Service Provider (PSP) on behalf of the merchant. Once decrypted, the token needs to be passed to the payment service provider for processing.

[image]

More info , you can refer to [Apple doc here](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/planning/) .